# Dual boot with windows

Tags: grub2

I installed ubuntu 13.04 in my laptop previously,before upgrading to 13.10 with liveCD.I have also windows OS which is installed in another partion.

But when 13.10 was being installed,my sister switched off the computer.Due to this grub was broken.It showed me that a file having extension '.mod' was missing(Sorry I cant remember properly,but the file was in /boot or somewhere).

Below that I saw 'grub rescue>'.So I decided to reinstall 13.10 and I was successful.

Now 'Grub 2' menu is working properly but it shows me only two options - ubuntu and advanced options for ubuntu.Options like windows7(loader),windows vista(loader) are missing which I was able to see when using 13.04.So, now I can't boot into windows 7.

I also ran boot repair with recommended repair,but it did not work.

The boot repair paste can be found at http://paste.ubuntu.com/6339275/

Also I want to know if there is any option to set boot entries under Grub 2 manually.
   And sorry for the grammatical error(s) in my lines.(if any).

Comment: My laptop model is Lenovo Ideapad Z580 which came with preinstalled windows7.

Comment: run this command to know which os was chained to your ubuntu system `sudo os-prober`

Comment: Ok,I am going to try it.

Comment: it showed
 me-/dev/sda1:windows 7(loader):windows:chain
 /dev/sda2:windnws vista(loader):windows2:chain 
/dev/sda4:windows recovery environment (loader):windows2:chain

Comment: now what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot using a windows 7 installation disk,goto repair windows 7 and then run diagnostics.
The 'boot repair' option might work,or run command prompt from the installation disk and run these two commands ->

> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot

The problem caused here is that your new installation override the mbr as it cannot recognize any other installation,it just displays the ubuntu boot option.
Hope this helps.

Comment: But my windows 7(64-bit) came preinstalled with my pc.So i dont have the CD.But I have an another CD of windows 7 which is of 32-bit.Will it work?

Comment: No matters,try that.

Comment: Ok.Going to try.

Comment: did you try `sudo update-grub`command on installed Ubuntu os.

Comment: Also thanks to Avishek Khandal.I want your e-mail too.Please post it.